# PHP simple concatenation of dynamic vars

Tags: php, concatenation, variables

How do I join a dynamic var to an existing var?

For example:

**My code:**

```
<?

// Gets value from url. In this example c is 1.

$c = $_GET[c];  

// Multiple static questions will be pulled from a list. 
// I use two as an example below. 

$Q1 = "Is this question one?";
$Q2 = "so this must be question two then?"

echo "$c: ";
echo "Q$c";  // returns "Q1" but not the string above.
echo '$Q.$c"; // returns the val 1

?>
```

How do I join the two together and get it to return the appropriate string?

Comment: Is this the exact code you're running? You've a couple of bugs there - `$_GET[c]` should be `$_GET['c']`, and you've got mismatched quotes on the last line.  Note that if you want to use variables in a string you need to use " instead of '.

Comment: Its not a bug, but php some kind of feature - first it look for c constant if it not found - it use it like a string key. Notice error should be thrown if error reporting is on.

Comment: @kirugan Yeah, a 'feature'. Like magic quotes and auto-extract (can't remember the actual name). :p

Comment: @Corbin thats why i said "some kind of", auto-extract - register_globals

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of dynamic variable names, use an [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) that holds multiple values.

```
$num = $_GET['c'];

$questions = array(
    "Is this question one?",
    "so this must be question two then?"
);

echo "$num: ";
echo "Q$num";
echo $questions[$num];
```

There are many, many reasons to prefer arrays to ["variable variables"](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php). One is that it's a cinch to loop over all the items in an array:

```
foreach ($questions as $num => $question) {
    echo "Q$num: $question\n";
}
```

Another is that you can calculate the size of an array.

```
echo "There are " . count($questions) . " total questions.";
```

Another is that you can easily modify them. There are [lots and lots and lots](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) of ways to manipulate arrays which you could never do with a crude tool like variable variables.

```
// Add a new question to the array.
$questions[] = 'Question 3: Who are you?!';

// Remove duplicate questions.
$questions = array_unique($questions);
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like what you're really looking for is an [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php):

```
$questions = array("Question 0", "Question 1", "Question 2");
$q = 1;
echo $questions[$q]; //"Question 1"
```

Otherwise, you're going to have to use some [var-var](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) nasty hackiness (*don't do this*):

```
echo ${'Q' . $c};
```

---

Also, `$_GET[c]` should be `$_GET['c']` unless `c` is actually a [constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php) (and I hope it's not since `c` would be a terrible name for a constant).  And you should use [`isset`](https://www.php.net/isset) rather than assuming that the `c` key exists in `$_GET`

---

Full example:

```
$questions = array("Question 0", "Question 1", "Question 2");

$c = (isset($_GET['c'])) ? (int) $_GET['c'] : null;
if (isset($questions[$c])) {
    echo "The question is: " . $questions[$c];
} else {
    echo "The question was not found";
}
```

---

You should probably also be aware of the draw backs of [short open tags](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag).  If ever a server has them disabled, all of your PHP code is going to break.  Typing 3 extra characters doesn't seem worth that risk.  (Though it is of course really easy to just mass find/replace `<?` -> `<?php`.)

Comment: Please note that the int conversion isn't needed, all array keys are strings so it will be converted back to a string.

Comment: @WouterJ Yeah, I like to avoid the possibility of an array though (since $_GET/$_POST/etc can only be either a string or an array).  It's just paranoia :).  (`?c[]=`)

Comment: Awesome answer! Duh, should have used an array!  What do you mean to use isset?

Comment: @PapaDeBeau Shameless plug for both myself and CodeReview: Read the "Assuming array indexes exist" section of: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/12757/basic-user-registration-code-in-php/12769#12769

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I get what you meant but I think this is the anwer:

```
<?php

$var = "Q".$_GET['c'];

echo $$var; // take care of the double dollar sign

?>
```

but arrays are more preferred of course

Comment: variable variables are never the answer to questions, using an array is the solution for problems when you think you need a variable var.

Comment: Well he was asking for something very specific, I'm not giving recommendations I'm giving an answer.

Comment: @Shehabox, just include a note about recommending arrays (and maybe an example. Wouter will likely remove the downvote. This site values correcting folks that are essentially asking the wrong question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use php `eval()` function like this:

```
eval("echo \$Q$c;");
```

but you should be careful not to put user data without validating, because it can lead to security issues.

Comment: Technically correct, but *what*?  An array is the proper solution, but even barring that, variable variables are a better solution than eval.

Comment: Wasn't me who down voted.  And no, it's not better to let the asker choose when they might choose the wrong thing. eval has very few legitimate uses and this is certainly not one of them.